# How to change the ?format=json ?output=jsonlike this in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

How to change the `?format=json`  like `?output=json` in ServiceStack

The format parameter name changed to output.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the built-in `format` identifier but you can add an additional Global RequestFilter to change the Response Content Type for any registered formats with:

```
this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => {
    var output = req.QueryString["output"];
    if (output != null)
    {
        string contentType;
        HostContext.ContentTypes.ContentTypeFormats.TryGetValue(output,out contentType);
        if (contentType != null)
        {
            req.ResponseContentType = contentType;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: My project is the 3.9.71 version is not supported HostContext.ContentTypes.ContentTypeFormats.TryGetValue(output, out contentType)